# Infinite while loop in Korn Shell

Tags: shell, while-loop, ksh

I have the following code :

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "1) Option 1"
echo "2) Option 2"
echo "3) Option 3"
echo "4) Option 4"

opt=0
while [ x$opt = "x" ] || [ $opt != "1" ] || [ $opt != "2" ] || [ $opt != "3" ] || [ $opt != "4" ]; do
        printf "Enter [1|2|3|4] : "
        read -r opt
done

echo "Option selected : $opt
```

The `while [ x$opt = "x" ]` means "while `$opt` is empty" in case you wonder.

Here's the output :

```
Will:/home/will> ./script.ksh
Enter [1|2|3|4] :
Enter [1|2|3|4] : jde
Enter [1|2|3|4] : 1
Enter [1|2|3|4] : 2
Enter [1|2|3|4] : 3
Enter [1|2|3|4] : 4
Enter [1|2|3|4] :
```

So when typing nothing or something unexpected it loops, OK. 
But why does it still loops when 1/2/3 and 4 are typed when it should prompt the last `echo` message ?

**EDIT :** 
I have added a `echo $opt` in the while loop, and it prints me this :

```
Enter [1/2/3/4] : d
d
Enter [1/2/3/4] : 1
1
Enter [1/2/3/4] :
```

So $opt received the user input as it should, but the while still never breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to avoid multiple `if` conditions using much cleaner `case` expressions:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "1) Option 1"
echo "2) Option 2"
echo "3) Option 3"
echo "4) Option 4"

while true
do
   case $opt in
     1|2|3|4)
         break ;;
     *)
         printf "Enter [1|2|3|4] : "
         read -r opt ;;
   esac
done

echo "Option selected : $opt"
```

---

About your problem, you don't need `||` between conditions, you actually need to use `&&` to check for all negative conditions:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "1) Option 1"
echo "2) Option 2"
echo "3) Option 3"
echo "4) Option 4"

opt=
while [ "x$opt" = "x" ] && [ "$opt" != "1" ] && [ "$opt" != "2" ] && [ "$opt" != "3" ] && [ "$opt" != "4" ]; do
        printf "Enter [1|2|3|4] : "
        read -r opt
done

echo "Option selected : $opt"
```

Also it is important to quote `$opt` inside `[ ... ]` as shown in my answer.

Comment: When using `&&` instead of `||` my code exist straight away with the ouput `option selected : 0`. It works when I remove the `[ "x$opt" = "x" ]` but this case if user input nothing, script will crash

Comment: Check latest edited answer. I changed `opt=0` to just `opt=` and changes quotes as well.

Comment: I have added the quotes and removing the 0 from `$opt` declaration and now it gives me `./t[7]: test: argument expected` :/

Comment: Copy/paste everything from my answer and run it. I have already tested it and it works. I have also added a case based answer that avoids all if conditions.

Comment: Thanks - I went for the case based solution, which's cleaner according to me, and that works like a charm :) Thanks !

Comment: Edit to make the `case` solution the main answer. If you're only checking a single expression it's much better than the multiple `[`...`]` tests

Answer (score 1):

`[ $opt != "1" ] || [ $opt != "2" ]` will **always** be true, whatever value $opt has.

Therefore, the behaviour is normal.